# Expose services via Istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am new to istio and I want to expose three services and route traffic to those services based on the port number passed to "website.com:port" or subdomain.

services  deployment config files:

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: visitor-service 
  labels:
    app: visitor-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      nodePort: 30800
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
   app: visitor-service
---   
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: visitor-service 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: visitor-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: visitor-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: visitor-service
          image: visitor-service
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
```

second service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-service 
  labels:
    app: auth-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3004
      nodePort: 30304
      targetPort: 3004
  selector:
   app: auth-service
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-service
          image: auth-service
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3004
```

Third one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway 
  labels:
    app: gateway
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      nodePort: 30808
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
   app: gateway

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway
          image: gateway
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

If someone can help setting up the gateway and virtual service configuration it would be great.

Comment: How you want to reach your services? Within the cluster? Through public internet?

Comment: This looks like a plain-Kubernetes setup that doesn't allow any external access right now (the three Services are all ClusterIP type); what have you already tried?  The [Istio ingress gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/) would typically do path-based routing on a single host/port and you'd need to configure VirtualService objects for that.

Comment: @Yayotrón through public.

Comment: @David Maze those services were exposed and working without Istio as load balancer type.

Comment: Agree with David, you're missing the istio ingress gateway. Basically you'll need: a load balancer (which I assume you already have), have this LB point to the k8 cluster and then set-up a istio ingress gateway and istio VirtualService(s), depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Yayotrón I know what to be done but I don't know how to make it work as I already have configured gateway and virtual service but it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you simply want to expose your applications, for that reason istio seems like a total overkill since it comes with a lot of overhead that you won't be using.
Regardless of whether you want to use istio as your default ingress or any other ingress-controller (nginx, traefik, ...) the following construct applies to all of them:
Expose the ingress-controller via a service of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`, depending on your infrastructure. In a cloud environment the latter one will most likely work the best for you (if on GKE, AKS, EKS, ...).
Once it is exposed set up a DNS A record to point to the external IP address. Afterwards you can start configuring your ingress, depending on which ingress-controller you chose the following YAML may need some adjustments (example is given for istio):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: httpbin.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: httpbin
          servicePort: 8000
```

If a request for something like `httpbin.example.com` comes in to your ingress-controller it is going to send the request to a service named `httpbin` on port `8000`.
As can be seen in the YAML posted above, the `rules` and `paths` field take a list (indicated by the `-` in the next line). To expose multiple services simply add a new entry to the list, e.g.:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: httpbin.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /httpbin
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: httpbin
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /apache
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: apache
          servicePort: 8080
```

This is going to send requests like `httpbin.example.com/httpbin/` to `httpbin` and `httpbin.example.com/apache/` to `apache`.

For further information see:

- https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: The istio ingress gateway is exposed by default as a load balancer and its reachable on the internet, my issue now is how to route traffic from the ingress gateway to the desired service as an example I want my visitor-service to be reachable from the internet via visitor-service.mywebsite.com or via mywebsite.com:8000 and how to configure the istio ingress gateway and istio virtual service to expose visitor-service.

Comment: @AbdnacerFried : The YAML above is showing you excactly how to do it. Simply change `httpbin.example.com` to `visitor-service.mywebsite.com`. There is no need to configure a gateway and virtual service object. Those objects are so called CustomResources (CRs) and exist in case the normal Ingress object does not fulfill the requirement a user has (which it does in your case).